# Post data to table: all data in table shows as 1

Tags: php, html, mysql, post, pdo

I have the script below running on my server when the postdata is passed all the fields in the database contain the number 1 and not the data I need

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "tadmin_admin";
$password = "Revolution1990#";
$dbname = "tadmin_datalord";

$db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=webpag.cu.cc;dbname=tadmin_datalord', $username, $password );

$ip = isset($_POST['ipaddress']);
$ip =strip_tags($ip);
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$useragent =strip_tags($useragent);
$username = isset($_POST['fpuser1']);
$username =strip_tags($username);
$email = isset($_POST['fpuser2']);
$email =strip_tags($email);
$password = isset($_POST['fpuser3']);
$password =strip_tags($password);
$passwordc = isset($_POST['fpuser4']);
$passwordc =strip_tags($passwordc);
$address = isset($_POST['address']);
$address =strip_tags($address);
$county = isset($_POST['county']);
$county =strip_tags($county);
$country = isset($_POST['country']);
$country =strip_tags($country);
$postcode = isset($_POST['postcode']);
$postcode =strip_tags($postcode);
$title = isset($_POST['title']);
$title =strip_tags($title);
$fname = isset($_POST['fname']);
$fname =strip_tags($fname);
$lname = isset($_POST['lname']);
$lname =strip_tags($lname);
$dob = isset($_POST['dob']);
$dob =strip_tags($dob);

$sql = "INSERT INTO liningdata ( userdata, ipaddress, username,email, password, passwordc , address, county, country, postcode, title,fname, lname, dob ) VALUES ( :useragent, :ip, :username, :email,:password, :passwordc, :address, :county,:country, :postcode, :title,:fname, :lname, :dob )";

$query = $db->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute( array( ':useragent'=>$useragent , ':ip'=>$ip ':username'=>$username , ':email'=>$email , ':password'=>$password':passwordc'=>$passwordc , ':address'=>$address ,':county'=>$county ,':country'=>$country , ':postcode'=>$postcode , ':title'=>$title ,':fname'=>$fname , ':lname'=>$lname , ':dob'=>$dob ) );

if ($query){
}
else{
} 
?>
```

Can anyone help me fix this problem? I am so stuck onto why my table only contains the digit `1` in all columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isset` return 1, so you have to change :

```
$ip = (isset($_POST['ipaddress']))?strip_tags($_POST['ipaddress']):'';
$useragent = strip_tags($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$username = (isset($_POST['fpuser1']))?strip_tags($_POST['fpuser1']):'';
```

and so on...

Comment: i have another problem aswell i use the script and its posts data but when i go to use the script again no data is posted

Comment: ** but when i go to use the script again** what do you mean? do you revisit tha page with form? and press submit button?

Comment: yes thats exactly how i use the form post the data then i go to use the form again but no data is posted but the first data always works

Comment: what is your table structure declaration? what is primary key? what are unique keys? try add `ON DUPLICATE` to the `INSERT` query

Comment: i am very new to pdo. i dont understand structure deceleration could you please show me an example